# Weird pointer appearing in linked list C when reading from a file

Tags: c, list

```
char get_directory() {
char file;
int i=0;
TD td;
FILE *file_no;
printf("Please Enter File Name: ");
scanf("%s",&file);
file_no=fopen("/ceri/homes1/j/jsc12/CS237/Assignment/cetaceans/data/observers_1.txt", "r");
fscanf(file_no,"%d%d%d%d%d%d",&td.day,&td.month,&td.year,&td.hour,&td.minute,&td.second);
for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
    Observer* obs=malloc(sizeof(obs));
    obs->timedate=td;
    fscanf(file_no,"\n%s%lf%lf",obs->id,&obs->location.lat,&obs->location.lng);

    add_observer(obs);
}

Observer* create_observer (char id[5],location locat,TD timdat){
Observer* b=malloc(sizeof(b));
strcpy(b->id,id);
b->location=locat;
b->timedate=timdat;
b->pointer=NULL;
return b;

void add_observer (Observer *n){
n->pointer=head.pointer;
head.pointer=n;
list_length++;

void print_list() {
Observer *next=head.pointer;
printf("|%d/%d/%d|%d:%d:%d|\n",next->timedate.day,next->timedate.month,next->timedate.year,next->timedate.hour,next->timedate.minute,next->timedate.second);
int i;
for(i=0;i<list_length;i++) {
    printf("%s %lf %lf\n",next->id,next->location.lat,next->location.lng);
    if (next!=NULL) {
        next=next->pointer;
    }
}
```

After the first two Observers are read in properly the next observer is added to the front however the when it reaches add_observer(obs) in the get_directory() method for the third time a weird pointer appears on the first Observer i added to the list which is now at the end of the linked list. Then when the third Observer is added to the linked list the second Observer points to this weird place and the first Observer is lost. Where the results at the end should be that 4 Observers are printed out with id, latitude and longitude, I only get the last two I added to the linked list from the file. Also I get a segmentation fault to accompany this.

Comment: `char file; scanf("%s",&file);` One character is a bit too small. 2) `Observer* b=malloc(sizeof(b));` should be `Observer* b=malloc(sizeof *b);`

Comment: At first glance you are not allocating enough space for `Observer`. Use either `Observer* obs=malloc(sizeof(*obs));` or `Observer* obs=malloc(sizeof(Observer));`.

Comment: 0) `char file;` --> `char file[FILENAME_MAX];`